# Android studio build error with error log of "process unexpectedly exit" in ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, build, ubuntu-16.04, build-error

I have installed android studio in ubuntu and whenever i try to create a new project the build is failing with an error saying `process unexpectedly exit`
I am using ubuntu 16.02 LTS version and android studio 3.2.1 version.

This is my build log.

```
org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources 
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-linux Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: Failed to start AAPT2 process.
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Process unexpectedly exit.
at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.startProcess(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:110)
... 9 more
```

I tried to find any help online regarding this but couldn't get any useful ones yet. If this is a normal thing to happen, i am sorry for asking this. I'm a noob to linux as well as to android studio.Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 7):

Same for me. I also have ho solution but workaround. In project-level `build.gradle` downgrade gradle version from

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.x'`

to

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'`

In my case it makes project build. Wish someone tells a right solution.

Comment: I have the same issues no matter how much times  i tried doing everything from the beginning. Tried changing the installation folders too. But this same error keeps coming up. I really wish to find if there is a solution.

Answer (score 7):

It  took alot of hours for me to found the solution.
Just goto your build.gradle file change

```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1' to
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
```

after that install the SDK tools(if it's ask to install)
After that Run your Project..
 Happy coding........

Answer (score 7):

This issue is because of latest version of AAPT library so please add below code in your **Project gradle** file under **allprojects** section.

```
configurations.matching { it.name == '_internal_aapt2_binary' }.all { config ->
    config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        details.useVersion("3.3.2-5309881")
    }
}
```

Comment: getting Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary' error

Answer (score 3):

downgrade the classpath from

```
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
```

to

```
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

**April 2019, the problem still exists... the version numbers have just become "higher"...**

---

It first started when Android Studio recommended plugin version `gradle:3.4.0` when I hovered the cursor over the project level `build.gradle` file... Once I do that, it downloaded the latest gradle dependencies and then recommended upgrading the gradle to `5.1.1` to support some new features...

Once that was done, gradle sync failed stating that the Android Studio version should be >= 3.4 to handle the new gradle plugin... (mine was the stable 3.3.2 version)

[image: Android Studio update forced by gradle update]

After the patch update of Android Studio, the gradle sync succeeded but any attempt to build the app failed with the cryptic "process unexpectedly exit" message!

So, I just went back to the gradle plugin dependency `gradle:3.3.2` as a workaround... Everything worked fine!

**Oh yeah, don't accept the update when you see this dialog (for now)!  :P**

[image: Gradle update dialog]

Comment: Hey, further, I understand that the Android Studio version and the gradle plugin version in the project's `build.gradle` should match, but this workaround requires otherwise!

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions which i successfully applied.
one is you can downgrade the gradle to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```

Second one is put this below code in app module gradle

```
  configurations.matching { it.name == '_internal_aapt2_binary' }.all { config ->
  config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
    details.useVersion("3.3.2-5309881")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is to downgrade the Gradle Plugin Version to 3.3.2 in the Project Structure. Just go to:

<kbd>Project Structure</kbd> > <kbd>Gradle Plugin Version</kbd>

Then scroll down to earlier versions. I have tried several versions in my Windows Ultimate OS. I think there is a problem with my current OS.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in case I did not do anything, and the easiest way to solve this was to update windows to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my gradle build tools to 3.4.2 and it's working fine now. Try this

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
```